# Page ordering by title in WP Admin is not working

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress

I want to generate a list of checkboxes in a custom meta field for a custom post type in the Wordpress admin. I am using ACF to create the fields. I can query all pages, but the orderby parameter is not respected. It just outputs them by date_created.

Here is my query:

```
$pageArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'nopaging' => true,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
  );
  $pageArray = array();
  $pageQuery = new WP_Query($pageArgs);
  if($pageQuery->have_posts()) {
    while($pageQuery->have_posts()) {
      $pageQuery->the_post();
      $pageArray[get_the_permalink()] = get_the_title();
    }
  }
```

You can see I create an empty array and enter the values from the query into the array during the loop. If I dump the array after the loop, the orderby parameter is not reflected. Moreover, if I dump the query object, it shows the SQL query and it is ordering by menu_order still.

$pageQuery dump:

```
    ...
    public 'request' => string 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_8_posts.ID 
    FROM wp_8_posts  
    WHERE 1=1  AND wp_8_posts.post_type = 'page' AND ((wp_8_posts.post_status = 'publish'))  
    ORDER BY wp_8_posts.menu_order, wp_8_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10'
    ...
```

Is this because the query is made in admin? I can certainly sort the array, once the loop is complete, but in an effort to understand WP a little better, Id like to know why this is happening.

Also, I can query this and it lists the pages properly....

```
$args = array(
    'authors'      => '',
    'child_of'     => 0,
    'date_format'  => get_option('date_format'),
    'depth'        => 0,
    'echo'         => 1,
    'exclude'      => '',
    'include'      => '',
    'link_after'   => '',
    'link_before'  => '',
    'post_type'    => 'page',
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'show_date'    => '',
    'sort_column'  => 'post_title',
    'title_li'     => __('Pages'), 
    'walker'       => ''
  );
  var_dump(wp_list_pages( $args ));
```

which dumps the page names in alpha order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a mixture of two mistakes.

My query was very wrong, as well as the ACF documentation. It should be

```
'post_type' => 'page', 
'posts_per_page' => -1, 
'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
'meta_key' => 'title', 
'order' => 'ASC'
```

ACF docs say it should be `'meta_key_num'`, but that did not work for me. I could order by the custom ACF field using `'meta_value'`.